# Different marker symbols

Tags: python

I am trying do multiple plots but I am not getting the specified marker symbols for the mass flow rate, total pressure and the static pressure as shown in the attached image.

---

---

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCMA5.png)

Comment: And what's your question? How much effort did you put in achieving what you want?

Answer (score 0):

I expect you are using matplotlib you can use something like this:

```
#Dont forget on import
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# red dashes, blue squares and green triangles
plt.plot(t, t, 'r--', t, t**2, 'bs', t, t**3, 'g^')
```

In the code **'r--'**, **'bs'** and **'g^'** means different types of markers.

More examples is in matplotlib documentation here: [Matplotliby.pyplot.plot](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot)

For better info you should provide more information. Post your code or update tags for your question. It very easy make plots with **matplotlib**.